# Detect a version of specific software on the client machine, load interop assembly dynamically and use

Tags: com, .net-assembly

In my case, there are 2 softwares I need to detect the version on the client machine, load necessary interop assemblies and use them:

- Microsoft Office (Excel)
- MapInfo Professional

The reason is, when I add references from my computer while developing the application, the client machine may not have that version, so the application fails at run time on the client side (by giving an error regarding to software version). For example, I use MS Office 2010 but user has MS 2007 on his/her computer; or I use MapInfo 11.5 but user might have MapInfo 8.5 and so on...

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Access Registry key : **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Office**

There will be a sub folder named some number (eg. 11.0, 12.0 ..) here. This number corresponds to the version of Microsoft Office Package. Each number represents a version. The list ::

- 1.0  : The Microsoft Office for Windows 1.5
- 2.0  : The Microsoft Office for Windows 1.6
- 3.0  : The Microsoft Office for Windows 3.0
- 4.0  : Microsoft Office 4.0
- 5.0  : Microsoft Office 4.2 for Windows NT
- 6.0  : Microsoft Office 4.3
- 7.0  : Microsoft Office 95
- 8.0  : Microsoft Office 97
- 9.0  : Microsoft Office 2000
- 10.0 : Microsoft Office XP
- 11.0 : Microsoft Office 2003
- 12.0 : Microsoft Office 2007
- 13.0 : Microsoft Office 2010
- 14.0 : Microsoft Office 2013

So through this number the version can be detected. This is just one simple method. But there could be more simpler and better ways.

Comment: thanks. now I need to load the assembly and use it. could you provide an example if you know more deeply about this?